# Build error: "duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ [...]"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I was installing push notification in my react native apps and I think I messed up while installing in one of them. When I try to install the app in the simulator I face the following error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_RCTPushNotificationManager._remoteNotificationCallbacks in:
    /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTPushNotification.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
    /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTPSStripe.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTPushNotificationManager in:


/Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTPushNotification.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
/Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTPSStripe.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTPushNotificationManager in:
/Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/l

ibRCTPushNotification.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
/Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTPSStripe.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_RCTPushNotificationManager._requestPermissionsResolveBlock in:
        /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTPushNotification.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
        /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTPSStripe.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
    duplicate symbol _RCTRemoteNotificationReceived in:
        /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTPushNotification.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
        /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTPSStripe.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
    ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

libRCTPushNotification.a is the library that I linked.

I deleted the build folder under `/ios` but it still failed. I think I declared this library twice somewhere but I dont see anything wrong in xCode. Any help is appreciated!